# Google querying elements of an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var acronyms=["fubar","snafu","gnu"];
```

Does jQuery have a method that would allow me to take each element of this array, and perform a Google search such that:

```
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=i
```

is sent, where **i** is each element of the array? I have an understanding that XSS attack warnings might come from the browser but that's fine for now as this is just an exercise. The actual implementation I'll be using this on is on the same domain as the rest of the project and won't be mistaken as trickery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) together.

```
$.each(acronyms, function(index, element){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/search?q=" + element
  });
});​
```

Comment: Indeed, but can someone explain the need for using .ajax to me please?

Comment: @derek8, `$.ajax` allows you to perform *asynchronous* requests and process them.

Comment: @derek8 It basically allows you to update some content without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, that would be a usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `foo` function you want to run with every element in the array

```
var acronyms=["fubar","snafu","gnu"];
$.each(acronyms, function(){
    foo(this);
});
```

(The answer is based on my understanding that the question about how to do actions on array elements with jQuery and not how to do forbidden actions with XSS...)